# Pre-order and Post-order Visitor

Tags: ruby, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree, visitor-pattern

I am working on a compiler written in Ruby and I am currently at the semantic analysis stage (type checking). I have an AST that I need to visit in two ways: pre-order and post-order, I was wondering what the best way to do this is in Ruby. I know that passing a block to `each` is essentially the Visitor Pattern, but since I need to visit in two ways(pre, post) and Ruby doesn't support method overloading, I am not sure how to approach this.

(Note: I am trying to have the Node objects control how they are visited, so my Visitor isn't bloated)

Here is what I am thinking about trying:

Two accept methods for each Node class `accept_pre` and `accept_post` that call the corresponding `accept_pre` and `accept_post` methods of other Nodes

```
class Node
  def initialize(a, b, c)
    @a, @b, @c = a, b, c
  end

  def accept_pre(visitor)
    @a.accept_pre visitor
    @b.accept_pre visitor
    @c.accept_pre visitor
    vistor.visit_node(self)
  end

  def accept_post(visitor)
    visitor.visit_node(self)
    @c.accept_post visitor
    @b.accept_post visitor
    @a.accept_post visitor
  end
end
```

Is there a better way to do this? Can it be done with `.each`, even though I need two orderings?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could fold the two orderings into one accept using an traversal option arg.  You can certainly use each over the node's members to dispatch the children's accepts.

```
class Node
  def initialize(a, b, c)
    @a, @b, @c = a, b, c
  end

  def accept(visitor, traversal=:pre)
    visitor.visit(self) if traversal == :pre

    order = traversal == :pre ? :each : :reverse_each
    [@a,@b,@c].send(order) { |e| e.accept(visitor, traversal) }

    visitor.visit(self) if traversal == :post
  end
end
```

Comment: You need to reverse the traversal of the children as well.

Comment: This actually looks like a great solution. I was unaware of the `send` method. Thank you!